# Match dates and time (hours) but not year

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a column with temperature data from 2012, for every hour during the year. I'd like that data to be used to approximate values during coming years by matching the date and the time, like taking the temperatures from the 3.10.2012 11:00 - 7.10.2012 15:00 range and when I write 3.10.2013 11:00 - 7.10.2013 15:00, it would pick out the matching data from 2012.

Is there any way of doing this, or would I have to remove the year from the cells and generate cells with just dates and time?

Comment: Why not try to filter the results to match your range?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example which assumes you have your data in a table with columns [Date1], [Temp1], [Date2], [TempEst]...

This array formula in [TempEst] would match it up:
`=INDEX([Temp1],MATCH(DATE(YEAR([@Date2])-1,MONTH([@Date2]),DAY([@Date2]))+TIME(HOUR([@Date2]),MINUTE([@Date2]),SECOND([@Date2])),[Date1],0),1)`

Don't forget Ctrl+Shift+Enter!